# Sinon unit tests fail when required module is undefined

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, chai, sinon, sinon-chai

I'm writing unit tests for the following file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
async function runRadar() {
    // some logic
}

runRadar();
```

The test file is:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Main tests', function() {
    before(function() {
        sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    });
    afterEach(function(){
        packageRadar = undefined;
        sandbox.reset();
    });
    after(function(){
        sandbox.restore();
    });

it('Test #1', async function() {
    packageRadar = require('../src/package-radar');
    expect(initRadarStub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
});
it('Test #2', async function() {
    packageRadar = require('../src/package-radar');
    expect(initRadarStub.calledOnce).to.be.true;
});
});
```

The first test passes successfully, while the second test fails as `packageRadar` remains undefined.
Please advise on what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's `initRadarStub`? Please provide a minimal completed code under test. Your code is lack of information

Comment: @slideshowp2 it's a function called within `packageRadar` there's no actual significance to it.

Comment: where the `initRadarStub` variable declares and what object do you export from `../src/package-radar` module?